# what does to_datetime() do in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d')`
I didn't understand what this code does? Can somebody please explain this.

Comment: When you read the manpage [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) what do you find unclear about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code convert your column `date` from string to datetime dtype. The `format` parameter indicates to pandas how to interpret the string.

Example:

```
>>> df
       Date
0  07/10/14
1  30/03/15
2  07/12/15
3  09/12/15
4  30/01/17

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   Date    5 non-null      object  # <- HERE
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 168.0+ bytes
```

Convert to datetime:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%y')
```

```
>>> df
        Date
0 2014-10-07
1 2015-03-30
2 2015-12-07
3 2015-12-09
4 2017-01-30

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   Date    5 non-null      datetime64[ns]  # <- HERE
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
memory usage: 168.0 bytes
```